# How to change size of input dialog box in java?

Tags: java

I want to change the size of input dialog box and its positioning.  Is this possible?

Comment: What kind of input dialog box are you using? Please clarify your question.

Comment: InputDialogbox resizes automatically on  the basis of message provided to it to display..

Answer (score 1):

The answer is the same as for any Swing GUI:

- Fill your JDialog or JOptionPane with a JPanel that uses appropriate layouts and that may override `getPreferredSize()`.
- Position can be set via `setLocation(...)` or `setLocationRelativeTo(...)`,
- all called prior to calling `pack()` (if a JDialog) and `setVisible(true)`.